# Matching/Counting lists in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{x: [a,b,c,d], y: [a,c,g,f,h],...}`. So the key is one variable with the value being a list (of different sizes).

My goal is to match up each list against every list in the dictionary and come back with a count of how many times a certain list has been repeated.

I tried this but does not seem to work:

```
count_dict = {}
counter = 1
for value in dict.values():
  count_dict[dict.key] = counter
  counter += 1
```

Comment: Dictionary keys must be immutable (i.e. fixed, so not a `list`).

Comment: The keys, as I understand, are strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could map the lists to tuples so they can be used as keys and use a `Counter` dict to do the counting:

```
from collections import Counter 

count = Counter(map(tuple, d.values()))
```